# Do cron and atd run jobs with the same user, permissions and environment?

Tags: linux, cron, at

What's the difference between running a bash script via cron and running the script via atd?

Is there any difference?  Is it specific to the distro?  If so, what about SLES 11?

Answer (score 2):

There may be some distro-specific differences, but the largest difference I've found is that `cron` scripts do not have any sort of default environment settings, while `at` scripts do. This may be the result of my never using `at` to schedule a job for after I've logged out, however, so take it with a grain of salt.